# interceptor concept for SqsListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, interception, sqslistener

I'm trying to do some basic actions once I'm getting a message from the queue - for example - setting the thread name.
This set of methods will be the same for all of the queue listeners. it is similar to the `preHandle()` interceptor concept for REST API.

conceptually , I want to do something like this:

```
@Component
public class GeneralMethodsQueueListenerHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

   @Override
   public boolean SqsListenerInterceptorPreHandle(QueueParam paramsStuff) {
      Thread.currentThread().setName("sqs_" + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(4));
      return true;
   }

}
```

I've tried to prevent creating my own custom SqsListener since the existing one is very straight forward and it fits our needs, except the code duplicatation for those common simple action.